# Generate HTML table and send it vie email in Apache NiFI

Tags: apache-nifi

We have an Java application which reads information from DB and generates HTML table via Freemarker like this:

```
<#if marks?size != 0>
<div>
    <p>
        <b>Total rows with information about broken utm-marks for ${date} is: ${total}. Displayed in current report: ${displayed}</b>
    </p>
    <br/>
</div>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">
    <tr class="tableHeader" style = "background-color:#f8f5e4; text-align:center; font-weight: bold;">
        <th>Report date</th>
        <th>Account Login</th>
        <th>View Id</th>
        <th>Utm marks</th>
        <th>Exception type</th>
        <th>Exception message</th>
    </tr>
    <#list marks as mark>
        <tr class="tableBody">
            <td>${(mark.reportDate)!""}</td>
            <td>${(mark.accountLogin)!""}</td>
            <td>${(mark.accountViewId)!""}</td>
            <td>${(mark.utmMarks)!""}</td>
            <td>${(mark.exceptionType)!""}</td>
            <td>${(mark.exceptionMessage)!""}</td>
        </tr>
    </#list>
</table>
<br/>
<#else>
<div>
    <p>
        <b>No information about broken utm marks for ${date}.</b>
    </p>
</div>
</#if>
```

This generated table will be sent to configured email.

Is it possible to build this type of application with Apache NiFi (without and with `ExecuteScript`)? Read from DB - fine; send email - fine; but what about templates and html table?

Comment: with groovy script you could even re-use your freemarker templates. or you could use one of groovy built-in templating https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/template-engines.html

Comment: @daggett, Can you, please, provide link to example or example with Groovy script with re-using Freemarker template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create `./templates` folder in nifi root folder

put there a template file `test.ftlh` with content:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Welcome!</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Welcome ${user}!</h1>
  <p>Our latest product:
  <a href="${latestProduct.url}">${latestProduct.name}</a>!
</body>
</html>
```

use `GenerateFlowFile` to inject following json into flow file:

```javascript
{
  "user":"Big Joe",
  "latestProduct": {
    "name":"green mouse",
    "url":"aaa/bbb/ccc"
  }
}
```

use `ExecuteGroovyScript` to merge template with data

```javascript
@Grab(group='org.freemarker', module='freemarker', version='2.3.31')
import freemarker.template.*
import groovy.json.*

class Const{
    static Configuration cfg
}
//on processor start
static onStart(ProcessContext context){
    Const.cfg = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_29)
    Const.cfg.with{
        setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File("./templates"))
        setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8")
        setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER)
        setLogTemplateExceptions(false)
        setWrapUncheckedExceptions(true)
        setFallbackOnNullLoopVariable(false)
    }
}
//flowfile process
def ff=session.get()
if(!ff)return

ff.write{InputStream rawIn, OutputStream rawOut->
    //assume json in flowfile
    def root = new JsonSlurper().parse(rawIn)
    Template tpl = Const.cfg.getTemplate("test.ftlh")
    rawOut.withWriter("UTF-8"){w-> tpl.process(root, w) }
}

REL_SUCCESS << ff
```

Comment: Sorry for the late question (all works fine btw), but do we need to close `Input/Output Streams` manually inside closure? I'm not good with Groovy.

Comment: the `flowfile.write` method is handling  closing of streams. it's a shortcut for `session.write` and here is the javadoc: https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.nifi/nifi-api/1.9.1/org/apache/nifi/processor/ProcessSession.html#write-org.apache.nifi.flowfile.FlowFile-org.apache.nifi.processor.io.StreamCallback-

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this without `ExecuteScript` (or similiar) would be:

- put the HTML template-text in a NiFi process group variable
- then use NiFi expression language function `evaluateELString` to substitute the flowfile attributes into the template.

This approach would have the advantage of being easy to maintain: the HTML template-text could be with the process group; there is no scripting code to maintain.

To illustrate this approach, suppose you put the HTML template-text into a process group variable, named `email_template`. Further, suppose a flowfile has the attributes set that are required by the HTML template (e.g., from a database). Then to get the realized email body, put the NiFi expression `${email_template:evaluateELString()}` in the value for the *Replacement Value* property of the *ReplaceText* processor (which precedes the *PutEmail* processor).

In the illustration above, the variable,`email_template` could be set to:

```
<#if marks?size != 0>
<div>
    <p>
        <b>Total rows with information about broken utm-marks for ${date} is: ${total}. Displayed in current report: ${displayed}</b>
    </p>
    <br/>
</div>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">
    <tr class="tableHeader" style = "background-color:#f8f5e4; text-align:center; font-weight: bold;">
        <th>Report date</th>
        <th>Account Login</th>
        <th>View Id</th>
        <th>Utm marks</th>
        <th>Exception type</th>
        <th>Exception message</th>
    </tr>
    <#list marks as mark>
        <tr class="tableBody">
            <td>${mark.reportDate}</td>
            <td>${mark.accountLogin}</td>
            <td>${mark.accountViewId}</td>
            <td>${mark.utmMarks}</td>
            <td>${mark.exceptionType}</td>
            <td>${mark.exceptionMessage}</td>
        </tr>
    </#list>
</table>
<br/>
<#else>
<div>
    <p>
        <b>No information about broken utm marks for ${date}.</b>
    </p>
</div>
</#if>
```

...and `${email_template:evaluateELString()}` would substitute the flowfile attribute values for `date`, `total`, `displayed`, `mark.reportDate`, etc.

Comment: Interesting solution! But what about List? It will work for 1 entry in flowfile. If I've 10 entires in flowfile I can't set attributes for all of them in 1 flowfile. I should split this file, but how to merge them again into single one after applying template?

Comment: Perhaps a _MergeContent_ processor could merge the flowfiles together before the _ReplaceText_ processor does the call to `${email_template:evaluateELString()}`. You might be able to set the `fragment.identifier`, `fragment.count`, `fragment.index` attributes for _MergeContent_ to group the related flowfiles.